# I am getting error on import the playsound module even after pip install playsound

Tags: python, python-playsound

This is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime 
from playsound import playsound

alarm_time = input("Enter the time of alarm to be set:HH:MM:SS\n")
alarm_hour=alarm_time[0:2]
alarm_minute=alarm_time[3:5]
alarm_seconds=alarm_time[6:8]
alarm_period = alarm_time[9:11].upper()
print("Setting up alarm..")
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_hour = now.strftime("%I")
    current_minute = now.strftime("%M")
    current_seconds = now.strftime("%S")
    current_period = now.strftime("%p")
    if(alarm_period==current_period):
        if(alarm_hour==current_hour):
            if(alarm_minute==current_minute):
                if(alarm_seconds==current_seconds):
                    print("Wake Up!")
                    playsound('audio.mp3')
                    break
```

This is error:

```
from playsound import playsound
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound'
```

Comment: You are running the code and installing playsound in different python environments

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Sayse. It's like you have not installed the 'playsound' package in the environment you are using.

Take those command to make a check:

```
pip --version
get-command python(Powershell)
where python(cmd)
```

Make sure the pip has installed the package to which environment you will choose.